# Explain this bash redirection behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, io-redirection

I was experimenting with redirections and pipes and did not understand some behaviour. I have this snippet to generate one line on each of stderr and stdout:

```
(echo stdout; echo stderr 1>&2)
```

It *seems* to work correctly, (try >/devnull and 2>/dev/null).

But the behaviour of these three commands confuses me:

```
(echo stdout; echo stderr 1>&2) > >(wc -l)
stderr
1
(echo stdout; echo stderr 1>&2) 2> >(wc -l)
stdout
1
(echo stdout; echo stderr 1>&2) > >(wc -l) 2> >(wc -l)
2
(empty)
```

Why does the last command combine the two streams? Or what else is happening to break my brain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because the second `wc -l` derives `stdout` from current command (stdout already redirect to fist `wc -l`), its output is also passed to first `wc -l`.

```
 IN   +-----------+   1>    +---------+         OUT
+-+--->echo stdout+----+---->  wc -l  +------------->
  |   +-----------+    ^    +---------+
  |                    |
  |                    |
  |                    +<------------------+
  |                                        |
  |                                        |
  |   +-----------+   2>    +---------+    |
  +--->echo stderr+--------->  wc -l  +----+
      +-----------+         +---------+
```

Comment: Based on the diagram, shouldn't i see the output `1` AND `2` then? The bottom wc counts 'stderr'. the top one counts 'stdout\n1'.

Comment: @EvanBenn `1` was consumed by first `wc -l`, so you only see `2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, followup: is there a way to do what I thought would happen? ie eliminate the upward arrow in your diagram

Answer (score 0):

It is something like

```
$ { echo stdout; echo stderr 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 >&2 | wc -l; } | wc -l
2
```